# How to use a downloaded TrueType font with Emacs and Vim under Windows 7?

Tags: vim, fonts, emacs

I downloaded the DejaVu font, and installing the TrueType (.ttf) files to `C:\WINDOWS\Fonts` enabled me to use them in [EmEditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EmEditor).

How can I make Vim and Emacs to use this font as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## VIM

From http://www.netlinxinc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=45&Itemid=2:

> The Windows version of VIM that I am
>   using is the Win-32 console and OLE
>   GVIM flavor.  Assuming you took the
>   defaults during the installation of
>   the program, you will find the VIM
>   init file in the %DRIVE%\Program
>   Files\Vim called _vimrc.  Edit this
>   file and add a line that looks like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> set guifont=Lucida_Console:h10
> ```
>
> This will use the Lucida Console font
>   in size 10 regular.  You can use other
>   fonts, sizes and settings. The syntax
>   is basically:
>
> ```
> set guifont=font-family:size:style
> ```

---

## Emacs

Set

```
(set-default-font "XLFD")
```

in your `.emacs` file where XLFD is the X Logical Font Description. How to get that is described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Fonts-and-text-translation.html#Fonts-and-text-translation